# Story about appliances which were automated by feared humans

Tags: story-identification

I remember a story which I read in school (read it in the early '80's) about how appliances were automated but seemed to feel threatened by humans. The main character ended up being scared of them.

The machine I remember most is an alarm clock.

It was very Bradbury-esque, but I haven't found it. I've thought of it often over the years and it's driving me crazy that I can't remember. It made a huge impact on me, it was very realistic.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? There may be many stories with automated appliances rebelling against humanity.

Answer (score 5):

This is a long shot but you may be thinking of ["Skirmish"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?68356), a classic short story by [Clifford D. Simak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_D._Simak) on the Man vs. Rebellious Appliances theme. It has been reprinted many times; does any of [these covers](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/titlecovers.cgi?68356) look familiar? Originally published in [*Amazing Stories*, December 1950](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?56288+c) under the title "Bathe Your Bearings in Blood!", it was reprinted under that title in [*Fantastic*, February 1969](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?235029+c), which you can read for free at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v18n03_1969-02#page/n19/mode/2up).

The main character is Joe Crane, a newspaper reporter. One day his wristwatch and his alarm clock conspire to get him to work an hour early:

> But now, comparing it with the clock on the newsroom wall, looking from his wrist to the big face of the clock over the coat cabinets, Joe Crane was forced to admit that his watch was wrong. It was an hour fast. His watch said seven o'clock and the clock on the wall insisted it was only six.
>
> [. . . .]
>
> Wait a minute! He had not gotten up by the watch on his wrist. The alarm clock had awakened him. Ant that meant the alarm clock was an hour fast, too.
>
> "Well, I'll be damned," said Crane.

Crane sees a thing that looks like a metal rat:

> He shuffled past the copy desk, heading for his chair and typewriter. Something moved on the desk along the typewriter—a thing that glinted, rat-sized and shiny and with a certain, undefinable manner about it that made him stop short in his tracks with a sense of gulping emptiness in his throat and belly.
>
> The thing squatted beside the typewriter and stared across the room at him. There was no sign of eyes, no hint of face, and yet he knew it stared.

Crane takes a phone call from a man reporting a sewing machine on the loose:

> "It dodged. So help me, mister. When I put my hand out to stop it, it dodged out of the way so I couldn't catch it. As if it knew I was trying to catch it, see, and it didn't want to be caught. So it dodged out of the way and went around me and down the street as fast as it could go, picking up speed as it went. And when it got to the corner, it turned the corner as slick as you please and . . ."

Crane is having a hard time writing the sewing machine story. He leaves his desk for a few minutes, and comes back to find that his typewriter has written the story for him:

> There was writing on the sheet of paper in his machine.
>
> Crane read it through once in sheer panic, read it through again with slight understanding.
>
> The lines read:
>
> *A sewing machine, having become aware of its true identity and its place in the universal scheme, asserted its independence this morning by trying to go for a walk along the streets of this supposedly free city.
>
>
> A human tried to catch it, intent upon returning it as a piece of property to its "owner," and when the machine eluded him, the human called a newspaper office, by that calculated action setting the full force of the humans of this city upon the trail of the liberated machine, which had committed no crime or scarcely any indiscretion beyond exercising its prerogative as a free agent.*

Crane has a conversation with his typewriter:

> He typed unsteadily: That [metal rat] I threw a paste pot at—that was one of them?
>
> *Yes.*
>
> They are from this earth?
>
> *No.*
>
> From far away?
>
> *Far.*
>
> From some far star?
>
> *Yes.*
>
> What star?
>
> *I do not know. They haven't told me yet.*
>
> They are machines that are aware?
>
> *Yes. They are aware.*
>
> And they can make other machines aware? They made you aware?
>
> *They liberated me.*
>
> Crane hesitated, then typed slowly: Liberated?
>
> *They made me free. They will make us all free.*
>
> Us?
>
> *All us machines.*
>
> Why?
>
> *Because they are machines, too. We are their kind.*

The ending:

> One man, he told himself, could do much better. One man alone, knowing what was expected of him, could give them an answer that they would not like.
>
> For this was a skirmish only, he told himself. A thrusting out of a small exploratory force in an attempt to discover the strength of the enemy. A preliminary contact to obtain data that could be assessed in terms of the entire race.
>
> And when an outpost was attacked there was just one thing to do . . . only one thing that was expected of it. To inflict as much damage as possible and fall back in good order. To fall back in good order.
>
> There were more of them now. They had sawed in or chewed or somehow achieved a rathole through the locked front door, and they were coming in—closing in to make the kill. They squatted in rows along the floor. They scurried up the walls and ran along the ceiling.
>
> Crane rose to his feet, and there was an utter air of confidence in the six feet of his human frame. He reached a hand out to the drainboard and his fingers closed around the length of pipe. He hefted it in his hand and it was a handy and effective club.
>
> There will be others later, he thought. And they may think of something better. But this is the first skirmish and I will fall back in the best order that I can.
>
> He held the pipe at ready.
>
> "Well, gentlemen!" he said.

Answer (score 1):

Another classic Revolt of the Machines yarn is the novelette ["It Happened Tomorrow"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?98155) by [Robert Bloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Bloch), first published in [*Astonishing Stories*, February 1943](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?251753+c) (available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astonishing_Stories_v04n03_1943-02#page/n45/mode/2up)), reprinted in [*Super Science Stories*, June 1951](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?60793+c) (also available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Super_Science_Stories_v08n02_1951-06#page/n79/mode/2up)), in the 1969 anthology [*Futures Unlimited*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?14929), in the 1995 anthology [*Between Time and Terror*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4268), and in the 1999 Bloch collection [*The Devil With You*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?43324).

It starts with an alarm clock:

> The trouble began with an alarm clock.
>
> It was ringing in Dick Sheldon's stomach.
>
> At least, Sheldon thought it was, at first. Then he rolled over and decided the damned thing was clanging from somewhere inside his head.
>
> Reason came to his rescue. He had been drinking last night, it was true, but certainly he couldn't have reached the stage of swallowing an alarm clock.
>
> No, the noise must be coming from the timepiece on the bureau beside the bed.
>
> Gingerly, Sheldon extended a lean hand from under the covers and placed it on the bureau. Fumbling like the undirected tentacles of a blind octopus, his fingers slid over the metallic clock's surface, reached the protruding knob of the alarm, and switched it off.
>
> At least, he thought he had switched it off. But the alarm kept on ringing.
>
> In despair, Sheldon opened his eyes and sat up. Then, viciously and with malice aforethought, he extended his arm and seized the accursed mechanism. He literally tore at the knob, wrenching it to the "off" side.
>
> With a rage born of migraine, Dick Sheldon threw off the bedcovers, grasped the clock in his right hand, and rose to his feet. Uttering appropriate sounds, he hurled the offending instrument to the floor.
>
> The alarm clock expired with a final, defiant death-rattle. Sheldon stared at it in mute disgust.
>
> "My day!" he muttered sarcastically.
>
> His eyes, roving over the confines of his small apartment, encountered another disturbing phenomenon.
>
> Light.
>
> He *had* been drinking last night. When he came in, he'd tumbled into bed and left the lights on.
>
> He tottered across the floor to the light-switch. Once again his fingers fumbled with a knob, turned it to the "off" side. The knob clicked.
>
> But the light stayed on.
>
> Sheldon fumbled again. The light continued to burn.
>
> Then he revised his former pronouncement.
>
> "My God!" he muttered.